# Geometric dissection theory

Tags: dissection

Today, i realized that one way to prove the Pythagorean Theorem is to dissect the given right-angled triangle into 2 triangles similar to it, and apply well-known properties of ratios of areas.
So this fundamental theorem can be viewed as a consequence of the possibility to dissect a given right-triangle into 2 similar sub-triangles. 
My question is: Which branch of geometry systematically studies dissections of general polygons (or other shapes) into other sub-polygons (sub-shapes) of a given type, and the metrical properties that emerge as consequences of these dissections? 
My search is on-going, i have seen some relevant results, for example the problem of dissecting a random triangle into n similar triangles, so i'm asking for some guidance towards a systematic exposition of the relevant theory, in 2D, 3D or more dimensions..